# How to modify a specific XElement into a file.xml

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I'm playing with xml and c# wpf, i want to search through a simple file xml and modify a specific XElement every time i found it. Instead of what is contained into that line i want to put whatever i write into a textbox the actual code is this and for now i've only managed how to modify a single specific element

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string xmlFilePath = @"C:\Users\codroipomad\Desktop\slave\Test.xml";
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.fruitauthority.fake";

        var elBanana = xdoc.Descendants()?.Elements(ns + "FruitName")?.Where(x => x.Value == "Banana")?.Ancestors(ns + "Fruit");

        var elColor = elBanana.Elements(ns + "FruitColor").FirstOrDefault();

        //check se il file esiste,se non esiste lo crea
        if (!File.Exists(xmlFilePath))
        {
            File.Create(xmlFilePath).Dispose();

            if (elColor != null)
            {
                elColor.Value = box.Text;
            }
        }
        //se il file esiste setta il colore con valore pari al valore della textbox
        else if (File.Exists(xmlFilePath))
        {
            if (elColor != null)
            {
                elColor.Value = box.Text;
            }
        }

        xdoc.Save(xmlFilePath);
    }
```

the xml that i'm using is this(i've inserted it like a snippet html 'cause i've found only that way to show it to you)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FruitBasket xmlns="http://www.fruitauthority.fake">
  <Fruit>
    <FruitName>Banana</FruitName>
    <FruitColor>pinuzzo</FruitColor>
  </Fruit>
  <Fruit>
    <FruitName>Apple</FruitName>
    <FruitColor>Red</FruitColor>
  </Fruit>
  <Fruit>
    <FruitName>Banana</FruitName>
    <FruitColor>feffolo</FruitColor>
  </Fruit>
  <Fruit>
    <FruitName>Apple</FruitName>
    <FruitColor>Red</FruitColor>
  </Fruit>
  <Face>
    <Name>Banana</Name>
    <Eyes>feffolo</Eyes>
  </Face>
  <Face>
    <Name>Apple</Name>
    <Eyes>Red</Eyes>
  </Face>
</FruitBasket>
```

IN THIS CASE I JUST WANT TO MODIFY ALL THE FruitColor THA THE PROGRAM CAN FIND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for updating all Banana's Color to YELLOW use this code:

```
        string xmlFilePath = @"C:\Users\codroipomad\Desktop\slave\Test.xml";
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.fruitauthority.fake";

        var elBanana = xdoc.Descendants()?.Elements(ns + "FruitName")?.Where(x => x.Value == "Banana")?.Ancestors(ns + "Fruit");

        foreach (var item in elBanana)
        {
            var elColor = item.Elements(ns + "FruitColor").FirstOrDefault();

            //check se il file esiste,se non esiste lo crea
            if (!File.Exists(xmlFilePath))
                File.Create(xmlFilePath).Dispose();

            if (elColor != null)
            {
                elColor.Value = "YELLOW";
            }

        }

        xdoc.Save(xmlFilePath);
```

Comment: can you just me expalin why? why the problem was elBanana.Elements?

Comment: this code: 
xdoc.Descendants()?.Elements(ns + "FruitName")?.Where(x => x.Value == "Banana")?.Ancestors(ns + "Fruit"); will give you all the elements that are 'banana' in your xml there are 2 of them, in that case you have to use an foreach iteration and go through the elements and update it as you want to

Comment: ok and till there we're on the same wave but then you've made a mod:into the foreach this {var elColor = elBanana.Elements(ns + "FruitColor").FirstOrDefault();} became that {var elColor = item.Elements(ns + "FruitColor").FirstOrDefault();} the only question about is why elBanana became item, and why if i put elBanana ther it doesn't work?

Comment: you can't have 1 property for all Banana's Color element, each Fruit has it's Fruit color that's why you need to take all the colors individually from every Fruit and update them accordingly

Comment: perfect so doing that i can take in consideration all the elements inside xDocument